# Getting stored proc to vb

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, stored-procedures, ado.net, sqlclient

I need to get the title (report name) from a stored procedure in VB, but I have variable name “title” which need to use that stored procedure in order to get that title. How should I do this?

Also the output of the stored procedure has spaces which I need to remove in VB code.

The variable looks like this:

```
Dim title as string = 'titlereportname_' & Format(Now(), "M-d-yy")
```

How should I make that title not to be hard coded but come from the stored procedure?

I got the following connection:

```
Dim dt As DataTable
Dim conn As New SqlClient.SqlConnection()
Dim command As New SqlClient.SqlCommand
dt = New DataTable
conn = new SqlClient.SqlConnection(DataProvider.connectionstring(sDatabaseAlias))
conn.Open()

command = New SqlClient.SqlCommand
command.CommandType.Text
command.CommandText = "GetReportTitle"
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ProjectName", sProject)
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Link", sLink)
command.Connection = conn
dt.Load(command.ExecuteReader())
command.Dispose()
conn.Close()
conn.Dispose()
```

Comment: So you need to pass the title to the stored procedure in order for it to generate you a title?

Comment: You will need to set the [SqlCommand.CommandType Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtype?view=netframework-4.8), and use SQL parameters to pass any parameters to the stored procedure.

Comment: @GSerg correct 'code'

Comment: @NotProf Have you tried calling the stored procedure in your VB.NET code yet? You would use the returned value from that call for the `title` variable.

Comment: @AndrewMorton I don't have a return value

Comment: @NotProf Please add the code for the stored procedure to your question: it might make it easy for us to give you a solution.

Comment: Please apply ALL relevant tags and ONLY relevant tags. You've used the SQL tage but this question has nothing to do with SQL. You've used the MySQL tag yet you're using the `SqlClient` provider for SQL Server. You need to actually read the descriptions of the tags to make sure that they are actually relevant to your question.

Comment: If the SP returns just a string, then you could do `title = CStr(command.ExecuteScalar())` instead of using a DataTable, then change that string as needed.

Answer (score 0):

This line is nonsensical:

```vb
command.CommandType.Text
```

You need to set the `CommandType` property. It is set to `CommandType.Text` by default, which means that your `CommandText` is assumed to contain SQL code. If it actually contains the name of a stored procedure then you need to do this:

```vb
command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
```